# Umbraco: Associated items to multiple tag groups

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-tags

Assuming we have 2 document types: `TagGroup [DisplayName]` and `TagGroupItem [DisplayName]` with TagGroupItems being children of TagGroup. That said, assume we have the following data:

Color
- Red
- Green
- Blue

Finish
- Aluminum
- Plastic

Color and Finish are both TagGroups. What kind of data type would allow for the another item to be associated with 1 or more tag group items? That is, an item could be Color-Red and Finish-Alumimum or just Color-Red. Aside from manually creating a drop down for each tag group and associating it to an item, how can this be more streamlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to do this with [Multi-Node Tree Picker](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiNodeTreePicker&referringTitle=Documentation) of the great **uComponents** package.

Create a *datatype* based on Multi-node tree picker, configure it to allow only `TagGroupItems` to be selected (using *XPathFilter*).

Every *document type* which needs to be associated with x `TagGroupItems` then simply needs one property using this datatype.

This of course would allow to choose more than one `TagGroupItem` from the same `TagGroup` (for example red and green). If you'd like to enforce having only 0 or one `TagGroupItem` linked, you could define a *datatype* for each `TagGroup`, limited to their `TagGroupItems` and *Maximum node selection* set to 1.